# Best way to build a C++ program that communicates with an Android app

Tags: android, c++, sockets, opencv, tcp

I'm working right now on a openCV project, that does some video processing.

I have a C++ program that runs on a PC, with some cameras connected, and it does the calculation and stuff and an Android app that controls the C++ program (something like aperture settings and starting some special calculations etc) and has a livestream of one camera.

The question is: How can these apps communicate.
I thought about two TCP sockets.

- one for the LiveStream
- one for the control

What do you think? 
Will this work or is the a better way to implement this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: 'and an Android app that controls that '. ??? Unclear. What does that app? Controlling the C++ app?

Comment: Oh sorry. No, it controls settings like aperture for the cameras etc. Or starts some special calculationd.

Comment: A TCP client/server would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a good guess.
Sockets is a good solution for you.

But TCP socket for video stream is really bad practice. In case of minor network issues you'll get annoying hangs, etc.

Use **UDP** socket for LiveStream. Just be ready, that some of packets can be missed if WiFi signal is low or smth.

Comment: Do you plan to run this always in a LAN or also across the WAN? In the second case using UDP there may be a problem, if the mobile phone provider assigns private NAT IP the destination port will be unreachable...